# Empty Object ID for first DrEdit Doc in PHP Google API Drive SDK Example

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Ive worked through several errors to get this far with the Google API Drive PHP DREdit example, and attempted the setup on [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/php#setting_up_this_sample_application).

The OAuth2 appears to connect ok, and loading the DrEdit demo page.  However on first save the doc has no ID, and the DrEdit frontends `/public/js/controller.js` handles this with:

```
...
if ($routeParams.id ) {
    editor.load($routeParams.id);
} else {
    // New doc, but defer to next event cycle to ensure init
    $timeout(function () {
            editor.create();
        },
        1);
}
```

To me, this means get the ID the second time the doc is saved because it won't be present at the first time. Chrome console output (not expanded) shows on first menu File > Save:

> Object {id: ""} controllers.js:14
>
> Creating new doc angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Updating editor Object {content: "", labels: Object, editable: true, title: "Untitled document", description: ""…}content: nulldescription: ""editable: truelabels:
>
> ObjectmimeType: "text/plain"resource_id: nulltitle: "Untitled document"**proto**:
>
> Object angular-1.0.0.js:5525`

Then second save in the File menu:

> Saving file true angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Saving Object {content: "", labels: Object, editable: true, title: "Untitled document", description: ""…} angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Saved file Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object} angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Object {id: "[object Object]"} controllers.js:14
>
> Loading resource [object Object] Object {} angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Saving file false angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> Saving Object {content: "abc", labels: Object, editable: true, title: "Untitled document", description: ""…} angular-1.0.0.js:5525
>
> PUT http://company.com/svc?newRevision=true 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm concerned with the Object {id: "[object Object]"}  but a little stuck.  $routeParams.id on first go does not appear to have a valid file ID but not sure if its supposed to until the second save.  PHP SLIM framework consequently complains with

```
ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$id
```

How do I diagnose further?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there maybe a bug in the sample leading to this error. Please file an issue in the GitHub project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/issues) so we can follow up.